# Converting a Google Spreadsheet formula containing a range into an Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

**Without** using a script how to convert the following formulas into an Array Formula

1. =if(isblank(E2),"", average(E2:X2))
2. =index(E2:X2, count(E2:X2))

Thank you in advance for any assistance in this matter.

Comment: specify ur question plzz

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't think i can be any more detailed than that. Can you pls point which part is not clear to you?

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: Pls refer to 'tags'. This is for Google Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your formulas I assume you want arrayformula's to

1. calcluate the average per row
2. get the value of the last non-empty column (per row)

In [this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1onB-l4U0XOi5ND8niL_ioo0zSuU_ob0LCt-WSzKQA3Q/edit?usp=sharing) I entered this formula in Z2:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexextract(trim(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(TO_TEXT(E2:X23)&" "&REPT(char(9),COLUMN(E2:X2)=COLUMN(X2))),char(9)))&""), "[^ ]*$")+0)
```

and to calculate the averag I entered in Y2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(E2:E23), MMULT(if(isblank(E2:X23), 0, E2:X23),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(E2:X2)^0))/ countif(if(E2:X23<>"",row(E2:X23)), ROW(E2:X23)),))
```

I hope this helps ?

Comment: Hi JPV.  I've added 'sheet 7' to your document to demonstrate the usage. The formulas that i need to convert into an Array Formula are at c2 and d2 respectively. The functions are as the following ---  1-To calculate the average value of the range if there is data in the 4th column, ie (e2:e).  2-To show the last value of data entered in the range. tyvm.

Comment: Check the sheet you added and see if that works for you ? I also edited my answer ..

Comment: tyvm for assistance. That's one complicated string from a couple of simple formula. I would probably never figure it out without your help!

Comment: I'm having problem maintaning the 'current price' column format as 'number'. Pls refer to 'copy of sheet7' tab when you have the time

Comment: Can you check again.. formatted the input and output columns as number and that seems to work ?

Comment: adding new data seems to break it again :(

Comment: The whole range E:H must be formatted as number. When I looked the newly added rows were formatted as 'automatic'.That's why it broke.. :-|